# Избегание пустых строк при переносе данных в другую книгу

Tags: excel, vba, таблицы, макросы

**Всем привет!**

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста: есть макрос на VBA, который ищет в присланных отчетах (Excel-файлы с одинаковым макетом) данные и выгружает их в новый файл в общую таблицу.

Проблема следующая: в макете 1000 строк на листе, а нужно переносить только те, в которых есть данные.
Подскажите, как лучше сделать проверку на заполненность? Я так понимаю через первую ячейку (т.к. это по факту ID).

Заранее спасибо!

[image: Таблица Excel, в которой нужно удалить пустые строки]

Comment: В общем случае - копировать в массив и проходить по нему, проверяя каждый элемент на наличие значения. Либо копировать по одной строке, опять же проверяя (это дольше). В частном случае - попробовать использовать `sheets('name').usedrange.rows.count`, однако успех не гарантируется.

Comment: `usedrange` - используемый диапазон. А используются все 1000 строк макета. *nikolaysaveliev*, вариантов определения последней нужной строки много, и в зависимости от организации данных и работы с ними могут различаться.  Без примера могут быть только общие ли приближенные рекомендации.

Comment: @vikttur воспользовался вариантом из Вашего ответа, прошу прощения, что данных было недостаточно. Стало работать, однако не без проблем: 
With sh2
lRw = sh2.Cells(ra.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With # где sh2 - лист, ra - строки в столбце А
                For i = 1 To lRw
                    shd.Range("d" & shd.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = i + 3   
                Next i

И вот в итоге дальше выполняется код по копированию. Почему-то lRw берется, как 1 и если данные есть в других строках, то он их не выводит. Надеюсь, понятно написал

Comment: Комментарий  к ответу нужно размещать под ответом

Answer (score 0):

Определение номера строки с последней заполненной ячейкой в первом столбце:

```
With Worksheets("НашЛист")
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Woth
```

Диапазон для обработки брать от первой строки таблицы до строки `lRw`

Comment: Ненадёжно. https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2GGO.png - в A4 имеется пробел... В генерированных по шаблону отчётах подобная ерунда сплошь и рядом.

Comment: Каков вопрос (без примера), таков и ответ.

Comment: Это да... поэтому я и не решился на ответ, обошёлся комментом.